# Search and replace with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I'm using the below PowerShell script to search and replace, which works fine.

```
$files = Get-ChildItem 'E:\replacetest' -Include "*.txt" -Recurse | ? {Test-Path $_.FullName -PathType Leaf}

foreach($file in $files)
{
    $content = Get-Content $file.FullName | Out-String
    $content| Foreach-Object{$_ -replace 'hello' , 'hellonew'`
                                -replace 'hola' , 'hellonew' } | Out-File $file.FullName -Encoding utf8
}
```

The issue is the script also modifies the files which does not have the matching text in it. How we ignore the files that do not have the matching text?

Comment: Is there any option to ignore a few matching texts. For example the file also consist of file paths like c:/hola/hello.xml . I want to include a regex or condition to not change hola when it's between /hola/  or if it's a file name as hello.xml and change the other occourances.

Answer (score 3):

You can use match to see if the content is actually changed. Since you were always writing using out-file the file would be modified.

```
$files = Get-ChildItem 'E:\replacetest' -Include "*.txt" -Recurse | Where-Object {Test-Path $_.FullName -PathType Leaf}

foreach( $file in $files ) { 
    $content = Get-Content $file.FullName | Out-String
    if ( $content -match ' hello | hola ' ) {
        $content -replace ' hello ' , ' hellonew ' `
                 -replace ' hola ' , ' hellonew ' | Out-File $file.FullName -Encoding utf8
        Write-Host "Replaced text in file $($file.FullName)"
    }    
}
```

Comment: is it possible to output the files the script is modifying?

Comment: Is there any option to ignore a few matching texts. For example the file also consist of file paths like c:/hola/hello.xml . I want to include a regex or condition to not change hola when it's between /hola/  or if it's a file name as hello.xml and change the other occourances.

Comment: Sure I added it above

Comment: You could. I added spaces, but it wouldn't replace anything that ended with a period and wasn't wrapped in spaces. -replace is a regex replacement method. You should look into some documentation for that for more specific replacements.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion what I actually meant was not to filter folders and file names, but the content inside the text file. For example the content inside the text file is **hola hello C:/hola/hello.txt** I want to change it as **hellonew hellonew C:/hola/hello.txt** it should change only the text and the matching texts in file path inside the text file should be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

You've got an extra `foreach` and you need an `if` statement:

```
$files = Get-ChildItem 'E:\replacetest' -Include "*.txt" -Recurse | ? {Test-Path $_.FullName -PathType Leaf}

foreach($file in $files)
{ 
  $content = Get-Content $file.FullName | Out-String
  if ($content -match 'hello' -or $content -match 'hola') {
    $content -replace 'hello' , 'hellonew'`
            -replace 'hola' , 'hellonew' | Out-File $file.FullName -Encoding utf8    
  }
}
```